# Is pg_free_result() necessary, even if the result goes out of scope?

Tags: php, postgresql, memory-leaks

The PHP docs have this to say about `pg_free_result()`:

> This function need only be called if memory consumption during script
>   execution is a problem. Otherwise, all result memory will be
>   automatically freed when the script ends.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pg-free-result.php

I would (perhaps naively) have expected the resource returned by a call to `pg_query()` to be garbage collected when it goes out of scope.

In a hypothetical function like this:

```
function selectSomething ()
{
    $res = pg_query("SELECT blah FROM sometable");
    // do something with $res
    pg_free_result($res);   // required or not?
}
```

Is it really necessary to call `pg_free_result()` at the end?

In other words, if I call this function 1000 times, will it eat up memory to store all 1000 results?

EDIT: I'm talking about the typical case, i.e. `pg_connect()` instead of `pg_pconnect()`.

Comment: Depends, are you forcing a new pg connection, or is the connection persistent? If you're using a persistent connections, [the resource might not be GC'ed](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.resource.php). But why not profile the script. Write up a little test-case and check the memory usage. If it keeps on increasing until the end of the script, add `pg_free_result`, and run it again...

Comment: This is more a general question, regardless of the type of connection.  I know I could just write a test, but it bothers me that the documentation is so vague. A one-off test will only answer my question for one specific platform and version (PHP and/or libpq).

Comment: Actually, you've got a good point there. I've edited the question to state that I'm talking about `pg_connect()`.

Answer (score 1):

As Elias Van Ootegem rightly indicates you are almost certainly using a persistent connection. With persistent connections after the query the result must continue in memory because you may wish to gather more data from it (for example the last error).

So it comes down to good practice. If you are operating in an environment where you have 2M of available memory and your script can, at times, hit up to 0.1M of memory then the upper limit is 20 concurrent connections calling that script. After that further web requests are going to queue or drop. It doesn't take a genius to realise how vulnerable this might be to DDoS attack.

Best practice, then, is to empty memory just as soon as you are done with it. This goes for just about any programming or scripting ever. When the system is being stressed and demand is high the more requests that can be serviced inside the total scope of memory the better. If you can lower the maximum memory footprint of a script you can increase the number of concurrent connections that can reasonably try to call it and thus increase the load the script can handle.

The ideal way to do things is to release resources as soon as you can. Just because we don't and everything seems to work anyway during testing is no reason not to.

Comment: I have commented about this in Elias's answer, but that answer was deleted along with the comments. To summarize: no, this is definitely not a persistant connection. Not using a $conn parameter in pg_query just implicitly uses the last connection opened by `pg_connect()` (or `pg_pconnect()`). Persistant connections are something entirely different. Among other things, they will keep locks and transactions active between HTTP requests (if mod_php is used), which is almost always unwanted. We're using PgBouncer as a connection pooler instead.

Comment: As for best practices, PHP uses garbage collection, which usually makes it unnecessary to explicitly free() resources. They will be marked for garbage collection when they become inaccessible (i.e. when they go out of scope). Best practice in garbage collected languages is to let the GC do its thing. The question was if that also applies to PG result resources, which _do_ have a free() function, and from the test I posted as a comment to Joel's answer, it appears that it does. But that's just a test, not officially documented behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Here are my test results:

(before / after)

with: 631288 / 631384

without: 631288 / 631640

Feel free to run the test yourself with this code:

```
<?php
class test {
    private static $tests = 5000;

    public function __construct() {
        $dbconn = pg_connect("host=### dbname=### user=### password=###")
            or die('Could not connect: ' . pg_last_error());

        self::test(self::$tests, true);
        self::test(self::$tests, false);
    }

    private function test($times, $with) {
        echo ($with ? "with:<br />\n" : "without:<br />\n") . memory_get_usage() ."<br />\n";

        for($i = 0; $i < $times; $i++) {
            $res = pg_query("SELECT * FROM chowder");

            if($with) {
                pg_free_result($res);
            }
        }

        echo memory_get_usage() ."<br /><br />\n\n";
    }

}

$test = new test();
```

Comment: I cannot replicate your results for the use case mentioned in the question. Look here: http://pastebin.com/ghw1PHuE

Comment: By the way, your test directly affects memory usage by adding keys and values to $memory_usage. Remove those, and you get the same result for with/without (plus minus a couple of bytes).

Comment: Ah yes I figured it would ad a negligible amount using the array. I have updated my test and results.